# Do I set a DNS A Record for the new GitHub Pages to use their CDN?

Tags: dns, cdn, cname, github

GitHub updated their Pages service for custom domains yesterday and I'm not clear on one small detail. [They recommend](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages#subdomains) a CNAME record for `www.example.com` but [do not recommend](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages#apex-domains) using A records for the apex domain.

I want to make sure both `example.com` and `www.example.com` resolve correctly to `www.example.com`, and **also get the benefit of GitHub's new CDN**. Do I use a CNAME for www only then, with no A record at all?

This feels like a dumb question as I type but I'm just not getting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I use a CNAME for www only then, with no A record at all?

You would need to use a `CNAME` for the `www.example.com` subdomain, and an `ALIAS` record for your root domain `example.com` (aka., "apex domain").

As indicated in the help document you provided on [Setting up a custom domain with Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages#subdomains):

> Some DNS providers (like DNSimple) allow you to use an ALIAS record to
>   point your custom apex domain to *username.github.io*. If your DNS
>   provider supports this it will allow us to provide the full benefits
>   of our Content Delivery Network to your Page.

Elaborating on this using their DNSimple reference, an [ALIAS](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/alias-record) record is:

> ...a virtual record type that we created to provide CNAME-like
>   behavior on apex domains.
>
> For example, if your domain is example.com and you want it to point to
>   a host name like *myapp.herokuapp.com*, then you cannot use a CNAME
>   record, but you can use an ALIAS record. The ALIAS record will
>   automatically resolve your domain to one or more A records at
>   resolution time and thus resolvers see your domain simply as if it had
>   A records.

The example DNSimple provides for setting an `ALIAS` record is [here](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/domain-apex-heroku) (substitute `username.github.io` for the Heroku server in that example).

For other DNS providers, see their support docs on how to set an `ALIAS` record to a subdomain. If your DNS provider does not support setting `ALIAS` records, then you'll have to use an `A` instead, which will not provide the benefit of GitHub's CDN.

Comment: Yes I saw all this the docs but unfortunately `ALIAS` records [aren't a recognised DNS record type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) and require the use of a third-party paid service. I think I'm asking too much here of the free service & I'll forget the CDN for now. Free GitHub Pages hosting + Free CDN + Free www and non-www working isn't yet possible. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: No problem - yes, it depends on whether you have a DNS provider that supports `ALIAS` records.

Comment: @TomBrossman The ALIAS record is not a standard DNS record, unfortunately there is no standard at the moment for such feature (that's why we came with the ALIAS. Disclaimer: I work for DNSimple). Just a few (paid) DNS providers offer this proprietary feature. You could potentially use an A, but you will loose the benefits of CDN. The other alternative for you at the moment is to use a CNAME for the www and redirect the non-www to the www.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti thanks for confirming that. I understand there may be a performance hit for DIY workarounds but I was curious how to implement it. I also asked a [related question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/566230/how-to-do-naked-domain-aliasing-like-dns-hosts-that-support-it).

Answer (score 5):

According to https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-an-a-record-with-your-dns-provider/#configuring-a-www-subdomain

> If you configure both an apex domain (e.g. example.com) and a matching www subdomain (e.g. www.example.com), GitHub's servers will automatically create redirects between the two.

Here is my setup that seems to work correctly:

- in my DNS:

  - I've got a CNAME record for `www.my-domain-name.com` pointing to `myusername.github.io`
  - I've got an A record for `my-domain-name.com` pointing to `192.30.252.153` and `192.30.252.154`
- in my ghpages repo, my `CNAME` file contains `www.my-domain-name.com`

And this setup seems to work with Github's CDN.